# Mocking function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, async-await, mocking, jestjs

I have this function:

```
export const getGroups = async () => {
  if (userData !== false) return Promise.resolve(userData);

  try {
    const groupApiUrl = getDashboardPath(GROUPS_TAB_INDEX);
    const data = await fetch(groupApiUrl);
    userData = await data.json();
    return Promise.resolve(userData);
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
};
```

I'm trying to write a test for it:

```
jest.mock('../apis/getGroups.js');
const getGroups = require('./getGroups');

describe('getGroups', () => {
  it('calls api', async () => {
    // The assertion for a promise must be returned.
    const data = await getGroups();
    console.log('DATA', data);
    expect(data).toBe({
      groups: [
        { id: 1, name: 'fake data' },
        { id: 2, name: 'fake data 2' }
      ]
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

Comment: If I don't return a promise, won't the functions that expect a promise fail? For example `const data = await getGroups()`

Comment: gotcha, thanks. Also which trycatch are you refering to, the one in the orginal function or the mock? Also any idea why my test is failing?

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to have a conversation about code that isn't part of the problem - was just an observation, your code will work, it's just more verbose than it needs to be

Comment: no it's fine, i appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` can be used in Jest but you need to enable Babel. To enable async/await in your project, install @babel/preset-env and enable the feature in your babel.config.js file.

Source - https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async

Comment: Updated question, trying to figure out why my test is failing. My babel config is fine.